# Работа с ListView и Jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Доброго времени суток. Требуется спарсить статьи и отобразить их в `listView`. Парсинг идет все нормально, проблема начинается, когда требуется отобразить статьи в listView. Получается, что адаптер подгружает массив `arr` еще до того, как `Jsoup` спарсивает, т.е массив пустой в этот момент. Пробовал сделать присвоение адаптера `lv.setAdapter(adapter);` в `onPostExecute`, но там `setAdapter` "не видит" `adapter`. Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить задачу. Спасибо.

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    String text;
    Button button;
    Parser par;
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        par = new Parser();
        par.execute();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


    class Parser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void ... params) {

            Document doc = null;

            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://site.ru").get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (doc != null) {
                Elements text2 = doc.select("div.entry-content");
                for (Element temp : text2) {
                    arr.add(temp.text());
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: из onCreate вынесите его и сделайте тоже самое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Попробуйте так:
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    String text;
    Button button;
    Parser par;
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        par = new Parser();
        par.execute();

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);
    }


    class Parser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void ... params) {

            Document doc = null;

            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://site.ru").get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (doc != null) {
                Elements text2 = doc.select("div.entry-content");
                for (Element temp : text2) {
                    arr.add(temp.text());
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо! Все работает!